# Help! check_in': undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Hi Im getting an core error which is really standard  I suppose in Ruby but dont know what to make of it. I have a program that I have written. Its purpose is to register guests at a camping. You have a menu with 5 different options. 1. Checkin. When i do this I get a  undefined method `generateParkingLot' for #<Camping:0x10030a768> (NoMethodError)
When I choose Checkout I get a  undefined local variable or method`departure' for Menu:Class (NameError).
So please i someone has a clue to my problem it would be great. I will here paste all my code. The code is separated in different files and I have used require for the different files. Here though I will paste all the code in one trace. Thankful for all help.

-Sebastien

```
require 'guest'

require 'parking_lot' 

class Camping 

attr_accessor :current_guests, :parking_lots, :all_guests, :staticGuests

def initialize(current_guests, parking_lots, all_guests, staticGuests)

   @current_guests = Array.new()

 # initiera husvagnsplatserna
 @parking_lots = Array.new(32)
 32.times do |nr|
     @parking_lots[nr] = Parking_Lot.new(nr)

    @staticGuests = Array[ 
    Guest.new("Logan Howlett", "Tokyo", "07484822",1, @parking_lots[0]), 
    Guest.new("Scott Summers", "Chicago", "8908332", 2, @parking_lots[1]),
        Guest.new("Hank Moody", "Boston", "908490590", 3, @parking_lots[2]),
        Guest.new("Jean Grey", "Detroit", "48058221", 4, @parking_lots[3]),
        Guest.new("Charles Xavier","Washington DC", "019204822",5, @parking_lots[4])
            ] 

   end 

@all_guests = []    

  @staticGuests.each do |guest|
  @current_guests[guest.plot.nr] = guest
  @all_guests.push(guest)
 end                            
end


def to_s
    # creates an empty string 
    list = " "

    # loop from 1 to 32
    (1..32).each do |n|
        if (!@current_guests[n-1].nil?)
            list += @current_guests[n-1].to_s
        else
            # else adds the text "Vacant"
            list += n.to_s + ": Vacant!\n"
        end
    return list
end

def generateParkingLot

    randomNr = 1+rand(32)
    # exists a guest at the (0-based) position?
    if (!@current_guests[randomNr-1].nil?)
        # if so generate a new figure
      generateEmpty(array)
    else
        # returns the generated number
        return randomNr
    end
    end
     end
  end

class Guest

attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname, :address, :phone, :departure
attr_reader :arrived, :plot


def initialize (firstName, lastName, address, phone, plot)  
 @firstName = firstName
 @lastName = lastName
 @address = address
 @phone = phone
 @arrived = arrived
 @plot = plot
```

end

```
  def to_s 
    "Personal information:
     (#{@firstName}, #{@lastName}, #{@address}, #{@phone}, #{@arrived}, #{@departure},      #{@plot})" 
  end 
end                     


require 'ruby_camping'
require 'camping_guests'

class Main  

if __FILE__ == $0   
  $camping = Camping.new(@current_guests, @all_guests, @parking_lots,@staticGuests)
  puts "\n"
  puts "Welcome to Ruby Camping!"

 while (true)
   Menu.menu
  end
 end   
end 


require 'date'                     
require 'camping_guests' 
require 'guest'

class Menu

def initialize(guests = [])
    @camping = Camping.new(guests)
end



def self.menu  
  puts "---------------------------"
  puts "      Menu"                          
  puts "  1. Checkin"
  puts "  2. Checkout"
  puts "  3. List current guests"
  puts "  4. List all guests"
  puts "  5. Exit\n"
  puts ""
  puts " What do you want to do?"
  puts "---------------------------"
  print ": "
  action = get_input
    do_action(action)
end

# fetches menu choice and returns chosen alternativ 
def self.get_input  
  input = gets.chomp.to_i

 while (input > 5 || input < 1) do
     puts "Ooups, please try again."
     input = gets.chomp.to_i
 end 
  return input
end

def self.do_action(action)
  case action
     when 1:
        check_in
     when 2:
        check_out
     when 3:
       puts $camping.current_guests
      when 4:
       puts $camping.all_guests
      when 5:
       puts "You are now leaving the camping, welcome back!"
       exit    
    end
  end


def self.check_in
    puts "Welcome to the checkin"
    puts "Please state your first name: "
    firstName = gets.chomp
    puts "Please state your last name:"
    lastName = gets.chomp
    puts "Write your address: "
    address = gets.chomp
    puts "and your phone number: "
    phone = gets.chomp
    puts "finally, your arrival date!"
    arrived = gets.chomp
    newPLot = $camping.generateParkingLot
    newGuest = Guest.new(firstName, lastName, address,    phone,arrived,$camping.parking_lots[newPLot-1])
    $camping.current_guests[newPLot-1] = newGuest
    @all_guests.push(newGuest) 
    puts "The registration was a success!! You have received the  " + newPLot.to_s + "."
  end                          

  def self.check_out 
    puts "Welcome to checkout!"
    puts $camping.all_guests
    puts "State plot of the person to checkout!"
    plot = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "Ange utcheckningsdatum: "
    departureDate = gets.chomp.to_i
    guest = $camping.current_guests[plot-1]      
    @departure = departure   
    guest.departure = departureDate
    guestStayedDays = departureDate - guest.arrived      
    guest.plot.increase(guestStayedDays)                
    puts guest                                      
    $camping.current_guests[plot-1] = nil               
  end
 end


class Parking_Lot

attr_accessor :nr
attr_reader :electricity_meter

def initialize (nr)
    @nr = nr
    @electricity_meter = 4000-rand(2000)    
    end

def increase_meter(days)
    generatedUse = (10+rand(70))*days
    puts "Increases the meter with " + generatedUse.to_s + " kWh."
    @electricity_meter += generatedUse
end

def to_s

  "Plot #{@nr+1} Electricity meter: #{@electricity_meter} kWh"

end 
 end
```

Comment: Your post have some serious formatting issues. Please edit.

Comment: Yeah, you need to put four spaces at the start of every line of code so it gets formatted as code

Comment: Thanks for the help guys with formatting the code.

Comment: You should indent your code better, it would help us to read your code and it might even help you to find the issues.

Comment: Can you fix the spelling of "variable" in the title, and translate your comments into English please?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have changed some but I am now receiving a check_in': undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
when i choose the first option in the menu that is checkin. When i try the checkout I get a ruby_camping.rb:96:in `-': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError) which I guess means that 'guest' is nil and i cant convert nil into a number?! Grateful for all help!!!

Comment: Anyone got a clue to the problem Im having?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks (although I haven't tried this out) like some of your your 'end's are wrong.

The one which is causing your first error (generateParkingLot undefined) is that generateParkingLot is actually defined **inside** to_s, so you need an extra 'end' at the end of your to_s method.

As for the second error (departure not recognised), the folowing line in self.check_out is at fault:

```
@departure = departure
```

because there is no 'departure' variable.  (Perhaps you meant DepartureDate?).  I suspect there may be a few other issues with this code, but I'm afraid I don't really have time to check now.

One I noticed was that when you have

```
32.times do |nr|
     @parking_lots[nr] = Parking_Lot.new(nr)
```

I think you might want to end that, either with an 'end' or curly brackets, e.g.

```
32.times do |nr|
     @parking_lots[nr] = Parking_Lot.new(nr)
end
```

Although that would make your other blocks not match..  In general, just try and make sure your blocks are all defined properly (e.g. everything has a matching end).

Comment: Thanks for the help Grant. I did as u said and started checking he blocks to see that they all had matching ends. Did not find any missing though. Do you have any clue?!

Comment: Did you know that you need an end for those 'do' loops, like the **32.times do |nr|** from my respose?  It isn't like C# etc where you can have a single line without ending the block, and it doesn't end when you do a return statement.  That's why your generateParkingLot method doesn't work, because your **(1..32).each do |n|** method inside to_s isn't closed, so the to_s method isn't closed.  Put another End at the end of your to_s method and you should at least get the generateParkingLot method working.

Comment: Tricky to find a decent tutorial just on 'do' blocks, but this might help: http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/loops_2.htm